# How to fix: The description for event ID %i from source %s cannot be found?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log

I need to troubleshoot some WMI crashes we are suffering from. Unfortunately the event log doesn't show any details as the descriptions are missing. This is what the log says:

```
The description for Event ID 5612 from source **Microsoft-Windows-WMI** cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

HandleCount
4116
4096
10508
```

I have already worked through Microsoft's knowledgebase article on how to troubleshoot the "event message not found" problem (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/166902) without any luck.

The registry key `EventMessageFile` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\**WMI.NET Provider Extension**` points to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll` which is existent.

Comparing the registry keys to a system where this specific event id gets shown correctly doesn't reveal any differences. Also the `EventLogMessages.dll` has the same version and checksum.

Am I looking at the right registry key?

The path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\WinMgmt` only contains a key called `ProviderGuid`. But that seems to be fine, as the descriptions are getting displayed on a system having the same (and only this) key.

**[EDIT]**

I indeed was looking at the wrong registry keys. The right one to look for is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\Microsoft-Windows-WMI` which was completely missing. Also a key called `Enabled` and the `ChannelReferences` subkeys where missing within the provider configuration which can be found at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{1edeee53-0afe-4609-b846-d8c0b2075b1f}`.

Adding those keys made the WMI events to get displayed correctly. However it did only last till a reboot of the system. Now the registry keys are there as they should be, but still no proper display of the events... any ideas?

This are my exact registry settings that I have exported from a working system:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\Microsoft-Windows-WMI]
"ProviderGuid"="{1edeee53-0afe-4609-b846-d8c0b2075b1f}"
"EventMessageFile"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,\
  00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,\
  5c,00,77,00,62,00,65,00,6d,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,4d,00,67,00,6d,00,74,\
  00,52,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{1edeee53-0afe-4609-b846-d8c0b2075b1f}]
@="Microsoft-Windows-WMI"
"ResourceFileName"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,\
  00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,\
  5c,00,77,00,62,00,65,00,6d,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,4d,00,67,00,6d,00,74,\
  00,52,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"MessageFileName"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,77,00,62,00,65,00,6d,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,4d,00,67,00,6d,00,74,00,\
  52,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{1edeee53-0afe-4609-b846-d8c0b2075b1f}\ChannelReferences]
"Count"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{1edeee53-0afe-4609-b846-d8c0b2075b1f}\ChannelReferences\0]
@="Application"
"Id"=dword:00000009
"Flags"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: You seem to have gone through the basic troubleshooting steps, Maybe this is a 64-bit vs 32-bit issue. This article may also help: http://www.eventsentry.com/blog/2008/04/event-log-message-files-the-de.html

Answer (score 0):

Missing event ids can easily be added using the EventCreate command line command.
More information can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490899.aspx.

Comment: Please expand you answer with the information from the link.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Event Viewer. Had this same problem, googled it, and found the answer.

"Event Viewer was not restarted since you added the EventMessageFile entry in the registry.
Event Viewer caches the DLLs it loads for event sources. If you have changed the registry to give a proper directory or source name after the event viewer has been started, you need to restart Event Viewer." -ref: See point #6 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/166902/howto-troubleshooting-the-event-message-not-found-message

Answer (score 0):

Change format to Events from RenderedText

wecutil es

wecutil ss "subscription" /cf:Events